# More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. In non maven project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to Java and I directly started with Spring MVC(do not know if it is a good idea). 
I have created a sample spring mvc project and have added simple Home Cotroller. 
I ran the project as 'Run on server'. 
I have not created a maven project. Its a dynamic project.
I am getting following error:

**More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.**

I am using -
JRE 1.8,
Spring 5.1, 
Tomcat 9.

Following is my web.xml

[image]

Comment: No, that thread is for Maven project. Mine is non maven project.

Comment: Please help guys.............

Comment: Even if i create a small jsp page I am getting same error.

Comment: Please read the exception message and what it advices you to do. You are using servlet. Absolute ordering is servlet related.

Comment: @user2746466 the other thread is for a maven-based project but solutions are valid for non-maven projects too.

Answer (score 0):

For non-maven projects, you can solve it by placing `<absolute-ordering />` just before the ending of the web-app. In other words, put `<absolute-ordering />` just before the `</web-app>`. I had the same problem with a non-maven project and this fixed the issue.

Comment: how does your gradle file look at the moment?